# Binding issue MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, windows-phone

I have a ListBox that is populated through a ViewModel and a DataTemplate in which I also have a binding. The problem is the binding in the DataTemplate is not working. Here is my code:

**ViewModel:**

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (null != handler)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
#endregion

private string strHeaderText;
public string HeaderText
{
    get
    {
        if (null != this.Trips)
        {
            if (null != this._trips.name)
            {
                return this._trips.name;
            }
        }

        return "Trip";
    }
    set
    {
        this.strHeaderText = value;
    }
}

public TripTypeViewModel()
{
    this.TripTypeViewModelDataSource.Clear();

    foreach (TripType tt in TripsResponseTypeViewModelDataSource.FirstOrDefault().Trip)
    {
        this.TripTypeViewModelDataSource.Add(tt);
    }
}
...

private ObservableCollection<TripType> tripTypeViewModelDataSource;
public ObservableCollection<TripType> TripTypeViewModelDataSource
{
    get
    {
        if (null == this.tripTypeViewModelDataSource)
        {
            this.tripTypeViewModelDataSource = new ObservableCollection<TripType>();
        }

        return this.tripTypeViewModelDataSource;
    }
}
```

Here is my **View**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ItemsLB" ItemsSource="{Binding tripTypeViewModel.TripTypeViewModelDataSource}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding tripTypeViewModel.HeaderText}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: I doubt that even the `ItemsSource` is not populated correctly. Normally you should set `DataContext` to some instance of your viewmodel, then the Binding's Path will be `TripTypeViewModelDataSource` **not** `tripTypeViewModel.TripTypeViewModelDataSource`.

Comment: Yes, but I do this, because my ViewModel object is in a class that contains other viewmodel objects

Comment: I read your post and made it like this but nothing happens:

<Button Content="{Binding tripTypeViewModel.HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>

Comment: there is no `TemplatedParent` here (it just works for ControlTemplate), in your case it should be like this `<Button Content="{Binding DataContext.tripTypeViewModel.HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>` Not sure why you could misunderstand my answer like that. Note about the `DataContext` present in the Path.

Comment: I did this exactly, but "AncestorType=ListBox" is not supported on Windows Phone

Comment: sorry, did not notice about the tag. I've just reopened your question. Windows Phone is not my field. However the idea may still be similar. You have to set the source explicitly for your Binding. Also `TemplatedParent` should not be used in a DataTemplate. Somehow you have to point the source to the `DataContext` of the parent control (as well as other appropriate controls in the visual tree).

Comment: So I understand I have to point the Parent item of the data template and I did this with no result:
<Button Content="{Binding Path=tripTypeViewModel.HeaderText, ElementName=ItemsLB}"/>

Comment: Ah, if you can use `ElementName`, maybe it should work. Your code is still wrong, change the `Path` to this `DataContext.tripTypeViewModel.HeaderText` (note the `DataContext`).